# ui-router shows no default state url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Looking at the ui-router sample starting it I see that url:

```
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/
```

When I change the state:

```
 .state("home", {

          // Use a url of "/" to set a states as the "index".
          url: "/"
```

to this:

```
 .state("home", {

          // Use a url of "/" to set a states as the "index".
          url: "/home",
```

I see this when I explicitly click on the home button:

```
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/home
```

But when I initially load the demo app I see this:

```
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/
```

Why does the loading of the default route not show `#/home` but `#/` ?

But the default url is 'fixed' when I click the home button ?

I also want to see initially `#/home`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set otherwise option for $urlRouterProvider like this:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $injector) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
```

this will allow you to set default state other than /.

Comment: Thanks just the otherwise with home was missing.